# Project Euler #201

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I've been trying to solve [Problem 201](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=201) for a while now, but i couldn't come up with a solution for such large sets. Given that the possible reachable sums don't exceed ~300,000, i tried a randomized algorithm, but it only worked for smaller sets with enormous computation time. Then i've tried, without any success, a dynamic programming approach.

I've already given up, but i am curious how one would efficiently solve this problem.

Comment: Don't give up. You mentioned the important things, you need to combine them in the right way.

Answer (score 1):

SPOILERS AHEAD!

I thought to give a couple of hints for how I approached this problem (and to indicate how it fits in a general way to approach such problems)

HINT 1: formulate (or just write the code) a recursion for the following function

boolean existsRepresentation(int number, int maximalIntegerToSquare, int numberOfSquares)

where the function returns true if the argument number has a representation as a sum
of numberOfSquares quadratic terms of the form x^2, where the maximal x is  maximalIntegerToSquare. Thus

existsRepresentation(5,2,2) returns true because 5=2^2+1^2 but
existsRepresentation(5,2,3) is false since there are no different x,y,z<=2 such that 5=x^2+y^2+z^2

HINT 2: formulate (or write code) a recursion for the function

boolean existsUniqueRepresentation(int number, int maximalIntegerToSquare, int numberOfSquares)

where the function returns true if the argument number has a UNIQUE representation as a sum
of numberOfSquares quadratic terms of the form x^2, where the maximal x is smaller or equal than maximalIntegerToSquare (the recursion should involve both the function 
existsUniqueRepresentation and the function existsRepresentation from HINT 1
with smaller values for the arguments). Thus

existsUniqueRepresentation(5,2,2) returns true because 5=2^2+1^2 and there is no other representation of 5 as a sum of two different squares x^2+y^2 x<y (being the maximal y=2 as wanted or also otherwise)

existsUniqueRepresentation(5,2,3) is false since simply because there is no representation of 5 (and thus no unique representation) as a sum of 3 squares of 3 different numbers less or equal than 2 (there are no x,y,z for which 1<=x<y<z<=2 ..)

existsUniqueRepresentation(89,8,3) and existsUniqueRepresentation(89,9,3) are false because
89=8^2+4^2+3^2 and 89=7^2+6^2+2^2.

HINT 3 you gave yourself: use dynamic programming, in the sense that you need to cache every value that gets returned by either existsRepresentation() or existsUniqueRepresentation()
(actually this is called "memoization" in textbooks, and dynamic programming refers to a way to organize the cached values in order to compute without making recursive calls, but the point is always to cache solutions to subproblems).

so the general approach is: formulate the problem as a recursion.. and then cache everything which moves! (everything for which you have enough memory on your pc, that is..)

It works (here and in many other problems)!